# Change Background position for icon

Tags: html, css

I want to add a 5px spacing (top, left), between the icon and background. So to be more specific, I need the background-color to be lower then the icon. I'm not sure how I can do that.

HTML:

```
<span class="icon-background">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.icon-background {
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    background-position: 60px 60px;
}

.icon-background .fa {
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using an `<i>` tag there?

Comment: @whrrgarbl I use Font Awesome icons

Comment: oh, I see. That makes more sense!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `margin`:

```
.fa-pencil {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you only need 5px, use 'border'.

```
border-top:5px white solid;
border-left:5px white solid;
```